# Getting column values from table with variable with PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I've recently started using PDO as I'm trying to better my PHP skills and understand that concatenation has been deprecated some time ago.

Currently, I have built a basic "user control panel" system where the user registers and their details are assigned to the `accounts` table. On their `accounts` row, they have `business_1`, `business_2`, and `business_3` which are populated with the IDs of rows in the `businesses` table.

I want to lookup the ID of each of the `business_x` columns in the `accounts` row for this username, find them in the `businesses` table, and print the column values from each of the relevant rows... but I've no idea how!

I'm looking to figure this out as the syntax feels completely different to deprecated SQL PHP statements I've used. If you have any good resources for learning this better, feel free to let me know in the comments too.

Comment: google should provide plenty of resources, some may be easier for some while harder for others and vice versa. You can select the one which gets you going. That is how I did it, although I went the mysqli route rathan than PDO, which in my opinion is a bit easier.

Comment: Bookmark this one. http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be handled in a single query, so you probably don't need to ask this question in the context of using PDO. However, I'll present my answer as though it were a prepared statement.

There are a few ways you can do what you're asking, but the simplest would be to just do a `join` with an `or`:

```
select
    businesses.business_name
from
    businesses join accounts on 
    (
        businesses.id=accounts.business_1
        or businesses.id=accounts.business_2
        or businesses.id=accounts.business_3
    )
where
    accounts.id=?
```

---

For the future, it's generally better to have "multiples of the same information" stored in a separate table, rather than have "x_1", "x_2", "x_3" columns.  Ideally you would have a table for `accounts`, `businesses`, and `account_businesses`. The account_businesses table would have a column for the account ID and another for the business ID, and you would remove the business_# columns from your accounts table.

This makes for simpler queries; better segmentation of data for analysis; allows you to have an "infinite" number of additional companies per account; and doesn't clutter up your tables with a bunch of empty secondary/tertiary/etc columns.

A query with that method would be as simple as:

```
select
    businesses.business_name
from
    businesses, accounts, account_businesses
where
    businesses.id = account_businesses.business
    and account_businesses.account = accounts.id
    and accounts.id=?
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realise it was quite that simple. What I was trying to do was store the value of `accounts.id` in a variable and then try to insert that into a statement to find the relevant row in `businesses`. Old habits die hard.

Great answer!

Comment: An understanding of `join`s, `union`s, `group`ing, and subqueries, all go a long way towards simplifying your code, and improving performance. This simple join potentially reduces 4 individual DB calls down to 1, and removes a lot of the "busy work" from your code. :)